# Angular 9 formatCurrency has a serious rounding issue

Tags: angular, currency-formatting

I have an angular 9 application and I have written my own currency pipe. It looks like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { formatCurrency, getCurrencySymbol } from '@angular/common';
@Pipe({
  name: 'dutchcurrency',
})
export class DutchCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(
    value: number,
    currencyCode: string = 'EUR',
    display:
      | 'code'
      | 'symbol'
      | 'symbol-narrow'
      | string
      | boolean = 'symbol',
    digitsInfo: string = '3.2-2',
    locale: string = 'nl',
  ): string | null {
    return formatCurrency(
      value,
      locale,
      getCurrencySymbol(currencyCode, 'wide'),
      currencyCode,
      null,
    );
  }
}
```

I have discovered a very serious flaw in formatCurrency. I have a number nameliy 1.425. formatCurrency formats this as 1.42 which is very wrong. It should be rounded up to 1.43! There seams to be a very serious flaw in formatCurrency where numbers should be rounded half way up instead of down. Is this a known error and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. For some reason the value sent to the pipe was a string instead of a number so I fixed that. Second I changed the first argument of formatCurrency with Math.round((value + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100.

That fixed it for me.